# Could a sorcerer who controls cold plasma freeze objects?

Tags: science-based, magic

In my story with magic based off of scientific studies like light and biology in this story there is a character with the ability to control cold plasma. This character needs to function as a cryomancer with the ability to freeze most metals, organic materials, and water. However, I do not know about the full capabilities of cold plasma and its freezing ability. Additionally unless there is a way to create liquid nitrogen with a biological organ.

Edit for those who do not know info on cold/non thermal plasma can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonthermal_plasma)

So could a person who controls cold plasma freeze things like liquid nitrogen and if not how could they freeze things fast?

Comment: What is "cold plasma"? Never heard of it before.

Comment: I just added some info on what it is.

Comment: er... do you know how it works? the given link specifically said the term "cold" is a misnomer! or did you give the wrong link?

Comment: what do you mean "freeze objects?" as AlexP said, metals are already frozen. If you mean "coat with a layer of frozen water" you may want to reorganize your question.

Comment: Why does your cold fusion mage need to be a cryomancer? Why not just make them a cryomancer instead of a cold fusion mage?

Comment: Freezing metals is a misnomer here. I think you mean cool them under 0°C, the freezing temperature of water? Most metals are already 'frozen solid', as they are a solid at room temperatures.

Comment: @AlexP Aluminium doesn't always visibly glow in its molten state of 660.3 °C, because black body radiation only becomes really visible a little higher. It takes a really dark room to see the very faint deep red glow. And of course the gallium-indium-tin alloy that melts at 10.7°C, pure gallium melts at 29.8°C or roughly "skin temperature" far from black body glow.

Answer (score 1):

Cold plasma isn't cold by the standards of the environment you live in... it isn't really cold in any useful sense at all unless you're in marketing in which case *cold plasma* sounds, uh, cool. Plasmas necessarily have quite a lot of energy in them, because something has to discourage the electrons from reuniting with the nuclei and becoming a boring old gas again.

Non-equilibrium plasmas are simply plasmas in which one component, such as the electrons, have a lot more thermal energy than other bit, such as the nuclei. Some folks trying to do p-<sup>11</sup>B fusion in a [dense plasma focus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_plasma_focus) hope to generate a non-equilibrium plasma where the nuclei have enough energy to fuse, but the electron energy is kept to a minimum to reduce bremmstrahlung losses. Nuclear fusion is rather famously not a very chilly activity.

> So could a person who controls cold plasma freeze things like liquid nitrogen

No.

> and if not how could they freeze things fast?

Either they can just vanish heat somehow, or they can move heat from one thing into another, leaving the source cooler. The latter is a little less destructive to physics and thermodynamics, though it isn't purely cryo-magic cos some things gotta get warm, too. Being a heat-pump-mancer doesn't get as good a job title either.

Answer (score 0):

## The sorcerer can't freeze anything

After reading a bit about Non-Thermal Plasma (NTP) I would say the sorcerer can't freeze anything. The reason is simple. There isn't enough NTP to go around.

The user can 'control' NTP, but this is not defined well. However, control does not mean it can be conjured out of thin air. That means only existing NTP can be used. I tried finding sources of NTP, and it seems to be on short supply. If there is few NTP around, there is few to use on metals, water or anything else.

When there is too little NTP to control, too little energy can be removed from metals or water to freeze them (freeze meaning 0°C).

To solve this the cryomancer can wield tools to create NTP. The information is limited again,  so I base this on it's use case. This seems to focus on surfaces and small volumes. The tools required to freeze any significant amount of water, or a metal, are likely unpractical in size. I wonder if a truck sized version could freeze a litre of water in half an hour.

That means theoretically it might be possible, but in any practical sense it would be easier to grab a refrigerated truck and toss anything in you want to freeze.